# Event Hub: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'body' not found

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, delta-lake

I am trying to write change data capture into EventHub as:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .table("cdc_test1")
```

While writing to azure eventhub it expects the content into a body attribute:

```
df.writeStream.format("eventhubs").option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation).outputMode("append").options(**ehConf).start()
```

It gives exception as

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'body' not found.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsWriter$.$anonfun$validateQuery$2(EventHubsWriter.scala:53)
```

I am not sure how to wrap whole stream into a body. I think, I need another stream object which has a column body with value of "df"(original stream) as  string. I am not able to achieve this. Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create this column by using  functions [struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct) (to encode all columns as one object) and something like [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json) (to create a single value from the object - you can use other functions, like, `to_csv`, or [to_avro](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro), but it will depend on the contract with consumers).  The code could look as following:

```py
df.select(F.to_json(F.struct("*")).alias("body"))\
    .writeStream.format("eventhubs")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .options(**ehConf).start()
```